# What is a locally finite p-group?

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

A locally finite group is a group for which every finitely generated subgroup is finite.

My question is that:

What is the  definition of  a locally finite p-group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably it's a group where every finitely generated subgroup is a finite $p$-group (a finite group of order $p^n$). That is, "locally" modifies "finite $p$-group."

Comment: Equivalently, it's a locally finite group in which every element has order a power of $p$. (The general definition of a $p$-group is one in which every element has order a power of $p$.)

Comment: In summary: you can parse "locally finite $p$-group" as "locally" modifies "finite $p$-group", as Qiaochu has done, or you can parse it as "locally finite" modifies "$p$-group", which Derek points out is equivalent.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank you very much for the comment. I understood that by your comment,a locally finite p-group  is a locally finite group and also a p-group. That is, it has two properties.

Comment: @user1729 Thanks a lot. That is I can see it from two points of view by your comment. Is it  right?

Comment: @M.Ramana Yes, exactly. The phrase "locally finite $p$-group" is ambiguous, but this turns out not to matter.

Comment: @user1729 That's right. I understood. Thank you so much for your help.